# Fetch array values and insert it in DB as a row

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have on one form which have one button.onclick of button it will add a one one form if press it again again will add form as per requirement.now i want to take all added form values and insert in to DB as a row using php.Following is the used code.

**JS Code:-**

```
function addExpertFrom() 
{
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.className = 'expform';
div.innerHTML = '<label class="explabel">Expert Name: </label><input type="text" id="txtexpname" name="txtexpname[]" class="expfield" placeholder="Enter name of expert"/>\
    <div class="clearboth"></div>\
    <label class="explabel">Link of the expert work: </label><input type="text" id="txtexplink" name="txtexplink[]" class="expfield" placeholder="Enter link of expert work"/>\
    <div class="clearboth"></div>\
    <label class="explabel">Title of the review: </label><input type="text" id="txtreviewtitle" name="txtreviewtitle[]" class="expfield" placeholder="Enter title of review"/>\
    <div class="clearboth"></div>\
    <label class="explabel">Details of the review: </label><input type="text" id="txtrevdetails" name="txtrevdetails[]" class="expfield" placeholder="Enter details of review"/>\
    <div class="clearboth"></div>\
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Remove" onclick="removeForm(this)">\
    <div class="line"></div>';
    document.getElementById('expertform').appendChild(div);
}

function removeForm(input) 
{
document.getElementById('expertform').removeChild( input.parentNode );
}
```

**PHP Code:-**

```
 $txtexpname[] = $_POST['txtexpname'];
 $txtexplink[] = $_POST['txtexplink'];
 $txtreviewtitle[] = $_POST['txtreviewtitle'];
 $txtrevdetails[] = $_POST['txtrevdetails'];
```

This wiil give me a count of array

```
foreach ($_POST['txtexpname'] as $key => $expname) 
 {
    $count = $count + 1;
 }
```

now what should i do to achieve this task.plaese help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this php code

```
<?php
$arr_txtexpname = $_POST['txtexpname'];
$arr_txtexplink = $_POST['txtexplink'];
$arr_txtreviewtitle = $_POST['txtreviewtitle'];
$arr_txtrevdetails = $_POST['txtrevdetails'];

$sizeof_array = sizeof($arr_txtexpname);

for($i=0; $i<$sizeof_array; $i++)
{
    $txtexpname = mysql_real_escape_string($arr_txtexpname[$i]);    
    $txtexplink = mysql_real_escape_string($arr_txtexplink[$i]);    
    $txtreviewtitle = mysql_real_escape_string($arr_txtreviewtitle[$i]);    
    $txtrevdetails = mysql_real_escape_string($arr_txtrevdetails[$i]);  

    // insert here each row
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `your_table`(`field1`, `field2`, `field3`, `field4`) VALUES('$txtexpname', '$txtexplink', '$txtreviewtitle', '$txtrevdetails')") or die(mysql_error());
}
?>
```

**NOTE :**

I used the function `mysql_query` for an example to insert the row. You can must use `mysqli_query` or `PDO` as per your requirement in the project.

Comment: Remember that `mysql_*` functions are discouraged now due to security risks. In all production sites you should be using PDO or `mysqli`.

Comment: @BenedictLewis thanks for you suggestions. i know it. because OP hasn't describe about which is he using i just placed the example. he can use any thing else pdo or mysqli as he is using

Comment: I get that, but new users, especially ones with 1 reputation, tend to copy and paste an answer and never check back again so its important to make sure that they know that this is an example, not a recommended solution.

Comment: @BenedictLewis now its Ok?